# How to pass data from XML file in Selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xml-file

How to pass data from XML file into application and I'm using page object model with page factory.

**Code:**

```
public class LoginPage extends BaseClass {    

    @FindBy(id="EmailAddress")
    WebElement username;

    @FindBy(id="Password")
    WebElement password;

    @FindBy(id="EligibilityNumber")
    WebElement click;

    @FindBy(id="CaptchaInputText")
    WebElement captchavalue;

    @FindBy(id="loginBtn")
    WebElement Login;    

    public LoginPage()
    {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public personal_details login(String username1, String password1)
    {           
        username.sendKeys(username1);
        password.sendKeys(password1);
        Login.click();

        return new personal_details();
}
```

> testutils:

**XML code:**

```
public static void readxml()
{             
   try {
          File fXmlFile = new File("E:\\DATAFLOWAUTOMATIONFRAMEWOK\\xml\\a.xml");

          DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

          DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

          Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

          doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

          System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

          NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("staff");

          System.out.println("----------------------------");

          for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

             Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

             System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

             if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                String id1= eElement.getAttribute("id");

                //String  username1=eElement.getElementsByTagName("username").item(0).getTextContent();
                //String password1= eElement.getElementsByTagName("password").item(0).getTextContent();
            }
         }
      }
      catch (Exception e) 
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

**Test method code:**

```
public class LoginTest extends BaseClass {

        LoginPage loginpage;

        personal_details pd;

        private String password1;

        public LoginTest()
        {
            super();
        }

        @BeforeMethod
        public void setup()
        {
            initialization();

            loginpage=new LoginPage();   
        }

        @Test
        public void loginmethod()
        {
           loginpage.login(username1,password1);// how to pass code here, could you please let me know
        }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Too much work here for just an answer. I will rather give you the direction on where to move.

First you should learn how to supply your tests with test data:

- In [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders)
- In [JUnit](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests)

Then you should rework your `readxml()` method. Currently it doesn't do anything valuable. It should integrate what it parses from your file into data provisioning mechanism of the particular framework you have chosen.

A separate issue is how you parse your file. It actually depends on the file structure.

Once you have all the issues resolved your unit-testing framework will take care of proper provisioning your test with the data from your xml.